# "If X he would..." vs "If X he might..." – what's the difference?

Tags: modal-verbs

Please help me with the following sentence improvement question.

> If he smokes less he might get rid of his cough

My book offered four options to select from:

1. *If he smoked less he would get rid of his cough*
2. *If he had smoked less he might get rid of his cough*
3. *If he smokes less he might have got rid of his cough*
4. no improvement

My text book gave **1** as the answer, but I think it's **4**.

What do you suggest?

Comment: So basically you're asking about the difference between *might* (option 4) and *would* (option 1)?

Comment: 1 and 2 are grammatical, though they don't mean the same thing. 3 is grammatical but nonsensical; certainly no improvement. I don't understand 4.

Comment: Option 4 means that neither 1 nor 2 nor 3 is any better than the original sentence. number 1 is the closest in meaning, but not close enough to claim that it doesn't change the meaning. And to call it an "improvement" assumes the author meant something different from what he wrote.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Wrong. (2) is invalid because the condition is in the past and so the consequent can't use "might get" but must use "might have gotten". (3) is invalid because "might have got" is wrong. (4) is correct. (1) is valid but conveys a stronger claim than (4).

Comment: @user21820: Ah, I see you speak a different dialect of English than I do; mine does not have the rules you mention. There are many differences; for instance, _might have gotten_ is strictly American, though _might have got_ is perfectly grammatical instead in the correct context. Also in my dialect of English there is no rule that condemns (2); you must have learned the language in a different place.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Oh okay. I wasn't aware that the grammar differed so greatly. I knew of idiosyncracies like "have dove" in some dialects, but thought that the tense rule for (2) was common across most of them. I suppose the textbook was based on a similar dialect as mine, though I somewhat disagree with their given answer.

Comment: Most textbooks are full of incorrect rules; the authors try to make it simple, and their rules seem to work OK for all the sentences they can think of, so they must be right. For an example of what English grammar is really like, take a look at [McCawley 1998](https://books.google.com/books?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false), for instance. You can be pretty sure your textbook's author didn't.

Answer (score 1):

> If he smokes less he might get rid of his cough.

This is a conditional statement, proposing something which can possibly happen based on an alteration of present behavior (the condition.)

*Would* is also a conditional, but it is a past tense of *will*, as well. As such, the tense matters.

> If he *had smoked less* he might get rid of his cough.

*Had smoked less* is in the past. The rest of the sentence should be in the past as well.

> If he had smoked less he *might have gotten rid* of his cough.

Similarly:

> If he *smokes* (present) less he *might have got* (past) rid of his cough.
>   If he *smokes* (present) less he *might* (present) get rid of his cough.

However

> If he smoked less he would get rid of his cough.

is similar to

> If he smokes less, he will get rid of his cough.

While it may not be true (he might not get rid of his cough), it is grammatical and acceptable.

My $.02. Not a scholarly treatise, but I think possibly helpful.

Comment: No, wait. The OP believes that the original sentence (If he smokes less he might get rid of his cough) doesn't need any improvement (4) no improvement). I needed to reread that question :)

Comment: I think you should clearly identify *If he smoked less he would get rid of his cough.* is the correct solution, it looked as if you were advocating the latter i.e. *If he smokes less, he will...* Sorry about the confusion, please ignore previous comments.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I'm not advocating, but explaining. I think the question's choices are poor. For example, I'm not sure it's an "improvement". It's just mostly equivalent to the sample.

Comment: I think (1) expresses the speaker's doubt that the smoker will reduce his smoking, *if he smoked less* is in the past and often the PS is used to express an irrealis situation, whereas the original sentence seems to be offering a possible solution for the coughing.

Comment: I disagree. I may be overthinking.